# What means that four complex quantities under a condition are equivalent to 6 real parameters?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given four complex quantities $\alpha, \beta,\gamma,\delta$ which satisfy the condition $\alpha\delta - \beta \gamma = 1$. What does it exactly mean that the four complex quantities under this condition are equivalent to 6 real parameters?

Comment: What do you mean with "equivalent"? Perhaps that when writing the complex numbers as pairs of real numbers we obtain two conditions (real part =1, imaginary part=0) from the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four complex numbers are defined by eight parameters, four real parts and four imaginary parts. But the condition given:
$\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma = 1 = 1 + 0i$ gives two parameters, so if you know six of the original parameters plus this condition you would be able to find the other two.